# Does "posting some text" considers an answer

Tags: discussion, flags, not-an-answer

I've just read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130683/2628137), which doesn't really answer the question in my opinion.

Altough the user didn't just post **a link only answer**, or just said **thanks!** 
He repeated one of the comments and said some general things which may be true, but it's really not clear if that is even the OP's problem.

Should answers like this be flagged as *Not an answer*? Why not?

Comment: To start with: the question is not great, it lacks information to answer it spot-on. That answer is not an answer to me but I doubt if I'll flag it as such. Maybe a downvote...

Comment: Two things, they are a new user who doesn't have enough rep to comment, second I wouldn't flag it because it does seem like they tried to answer the question by at least providing some suggestions.   I would leave them a comment asking to expand possibly on their answer to provide more details.

Comment: Ick. Baleeting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there's the smallest doubt as to whether it's an answer or not, just cast a custom flag instead, and explain why the answer provides no value.

"Not an Answer" flags are reserved for things like "Thanks," "I have the same problem," and "Why is my sweater unraveling?"

Comment: What if the question is "What did the man say when his sweater started unraveling?"